# Android Xamarin - How do I start activity from a non-UI thread?

Tags: xamarin.android

I am using Xamarin.Android.  I would like to start an activity from a worker thread.  I tried the code below but it crashes with null exception.
The code may be called from an activity or even a worker thread.  The issues is that I do not know how to the current activity, intent, context, etc. that many other posted solutions use.

```
Android.OS.Handler handler = new Android.OS.Handler(Android.OS.Looper.MainLooper);
handler.Post(() =>
{
    StartActivity(typeof(MyUI));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just run your code inside of `RunOnUiThread` like so:

```
RunOnUiThread(() => {
    StartActivity(typeof(MyUi));
});
```

Comment: Wouldn't I have to extend my class with Activity to use RunOnUiThread?

Comment: You can pass in a `Context` to the class and use that. You need to do that either way if you want to use `StartActivity`